# Using Google Calendar API GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync Getting Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime'

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api, .net-framework-version

I am using:
VB.NET (visual studio 2015)
RestSharp v4.0.30319
Google.Apis.Core 1.20.0.0

This was working fine until I upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015.  I also updated all the RestSharp and Google APIs as well as switched .NET framework from 4.5 to 4.6.1 (which it made me do when I upgraded the Google APIs.

So now when I run it I get the following exception on this line of code...

```
Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(gclientsecrets, gscopes, "mysecretcalendar@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None).Result
```

and here is the error...

Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' has detected a problem in 'C:\Voxeo\SERVICES\SERVICE DEBUGGER\IVRServiceDebugger\bin\Debug\IVRServiceDebugger.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: The assembly with display name 'System.Runtime' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The project compiles just fine.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or Asp.net? From the AppDomain in your StackTrace I'm assuming Asp.net. If so make sure the dependencies in all your files match up to the correct version, and there are no duplicate references to 'System.Runtime' in your web.config.

Comment: This is a windows service in Visual Studio.  There are no references to System.Runtime in the app.config. Not sure how to check that the dependencies in all my files match up to the correct version.thx

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ab6ffa7-0047-481b-a097-8e5c92eea72a/bindingfailure-occurred-message-managed-debugging-assistant-bindingfailure-has-detected-a?forum=visualstudiogeneral), maybe the cause is that the specified assembly can not be loaded successfully and a `FileNotFoundException` or `FileLoadException` is thrown. You may install the request assembly or copy the assembly to the application directory then try it again. For `BindingFailure`, you may check the given [resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172215(v=vs.110).aspx#Resolution) which suggested to determine if the assembly is at the location requested. Then resolve the cause based on the preceding determination given in the previos link.

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment this out in the app.config (NOT FOR THE PROJECT BUT FOR THE PROJECT THAT REFERENCED IT)

-->